# PHP mysql how to relationship three tables showing outputs from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

I have this diagram [image: POST WITH FEEDS]

What I wanna do is have this output: 
[image: Likes post - like Facebook]

How do you manage to do the query of this one?

I have this code

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, 
       users.screenname, posts.post_id, posts.user_id,
       posts.post, posts.upload_name, 
       posts.post_type, posts.date_posted
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.posts posts ON (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
ORDER BY posts.pid DESC
//PROBLEM with this one is that it only views the post from all users.

//SO I added
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS friends, SUM(user_id = ?) AS you, user_id
FROM feeds WHERE post_id = ?
//This one will give you two fields containing how many different users **feeds** the
post
```

Please help guys. Actually this one I am just following **Facebook's** "LIKE" status
the only thing is I'm not an amateur with this kind of stuff so I'd be glad to hear all your answers. I really need your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want an outer join with the `feeds` table (in order to retain all `posts` even if there are no associated `feeds`), then `GROUP BY post.pid` in order to amalgamate together all such feeds for each post, and `SELECT` the desired information.

I use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to obtain a comma-separated list of all users (up to [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)) who have 
a "feed" for the given post (you can change the delimiter with the `SEPARATOR` modifier, if so desired).

```sql
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, 
       users.screenname, posts.post_id, posts.user_id,
       posts.post, posts.upload_name, 
       posts.post_type, posts.date_posted,
       COUNT(feeds.user_id) AS friends,   -- number of "likes"
       SUM(feeds.user_id = ?) AS you,     -- did I like this?
       GROUP_CONCAT(feeds.user_id)        -- who likes it?
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.posts posts ON (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.feeds feeds ON (posts.post_id = feeds.post_id)
GROUP BY posts.pid
ORDER BY posts.pid DESC
```

---

**UPDATE**

To obtain the full name of users who have "liked" the post, excluding oneself, one needs to join the `users` table a second time:

```sql
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, 
       users.screenname, posts.post_id, posts.user_id,
       posts.post, posts.upload_name, 
       posts.post_type, posts.date_posted,
       COUNT(feeds.user_id) AS friends,                      -- number of "likes"
       SUM(feeds.user_id = ?) AS you,                        -- did I like this?
       GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE WHEN NOT likes.user_id = ? THEN                -- exclude self
           CONCAT_WS(' ', likes.firstname, likes.lastname)   -- full names
         END
       )
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.posts posts ON (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.feeds feeds ON (posts.post_id = feeds.post_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.users likes ON (feeds.user_id = likes.user_id)
GROUP BY posts.pid
ORDER BY posts.pid DESC
```

Comment: THanks much mate! But bro, about this line "SUM(user_id = ?) AS you,           -- did I like this? GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)" should it be "feeds.user_id"? I'm having an error saying: "Column user_id in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Yes, sorry: `feeds.user_id`.  Updated.

Comment: uhm mate! I got a little problem here, how do you select/replace the field "GROUP_CONCAT (feeds.user_id) as names"-output from user_id to name excluding "you" who liked/feed the post? @eggyal

Comment: @PeterWateber: `GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?))` where `?` is "my" id.  Bear in mind the `COUNT` also includes oneself too (unless you add a similar `NULLIF` around its argument).

Comment: last one question regarding the output, I'm trying to figure out how to select the names from users table from the output GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?)). So I tried converting it to an array, but it gives me an output "Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] =>   "" [1] => "" ) Array ( [0] => "")"-where it outputs the user_id however, how do you make "GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?))" to be query for another table? I kinda like having a hard time doing this I'm so sorry I'm not really good at this.

Comment: You could merge the comma-separated string from `GROUP_CONCAT` into a  new SQL command: `WHERE user_id IN (<comma-separated values here>)`, but if you ultimately want the user names, you can modify the above query to give you them instead of user ids.

Comment: WOOOO!!! You just saved my day! Thank you so much mate! Have a good day didn't know about the advance query part on GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE WHEN NOT likes.user_id = ? THEN                -- exclude self
           CONCAT_WS(' ', likes.firstname, likes.lastname)   -- full names
         END
       )

Comment: hey bro @eggyal! I gotta new problem here... its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570154/mysql-related-fields the same as the output above only there are now 4 tables. The new one is the friend table.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to do it for all the users and simultaneously get the feeds, You have to join this `feed` table:

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, 
   u.screenname, p.post_id, p.user_id,
   p.post, p.upload_name, 
   p.post_type, p.date_posted,
   COUNT(f.user_id) AS friends, SUM(f.user_id = ?) AS you
FROM website.users u
INNER JOIN website.posts p ON (u.user_id = p.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.feeds f ON (p.post_id = f.post_id)
GROUP BY p.pid
ORDER BY p.pid DESC
```

This one should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks mate! trying to understand everything