# mysql related fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

These 4 fields are related to each other

[image: Friends - posts - users - feeds]

I want it to output it as: [image]

In my **query**:

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.screenname, posts.post_id, posts.user_id,
posts.post, posts.upload_name, posts.post_type, 
DATE_FORMAT(posts.date_posted, '%M %d, %Y %r') AS date, 
COUNT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?)) AS everybody, SUM(feeds.user_id = ?) AS you,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN NOT likes.user_id = ? THEN 
             CONCAT_WS(' ', likes.firstname, likes.lastname)
                    END
            ) as names
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.posts posts ON (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.feeds feeds ON (posts.post_id = feeds.post_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.users likes ON (feeds.user_id = likes.user_id)
GROUP BY posts.pid
ORDER BY posts.pid DESC
```

Now, I am having a problem on which part should I join the **friends table**, 
  I want to display **all the posts from friend_id or user_id** and also the post from user who is currently logged in. If no friend matched on the **friend table**, then just output all the posts from user. Please guys I need your help.

friends.friend_id = friend of the current user

friends.user_id = current friend of the user

Thus, friends.friend_id = posts.user_id or friends.user_id = posts.user_id

If my friends table is not understandable, please help me change it to make it better.

Comment: Please explain better what you want to achieve, and how friends are related to users and posts ...

Comment: The friends table is related to user and posts.
The friends.friend_id = posts.user_id = users.user_id

All posts from posts will be outputted using the ff conditions:
1.) if friends.friends_id or friends.user_id matches posts.user_id
2.) if no match then just select all the posts from posts.user_id = current logged user.

Comment: How `feeds` is related to other tables? How to distinguish between `you` and `everybody` in `feeds`?

Comment: You can test the sql statement above. the feeds are the same as "LIKE" on facebook. the you and everybody counts all the feeds or likes from a certain user using user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to see posts either from the user, or from his friends. Therefore, instead of joining with users, join with the subquery, like this:

```sql
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.screenname,
       posts.post_id, posts.user_id, posts.post, posts.upload_name,
       posts.post_type, DATE_FORMAT(posts.date_posted, '%M %d, %Y %r') AS date, 
       COUNT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?)) AS everybody,
       SUM(feeds.user_id = ?) AS you,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN NOT likes.user_id = ? THEN 
             CONCAT_WS(' ', likes.firstname, likes.lastname) END) as names
  FROM (SELECT user_id FROM website.users WHERE user_id = ?
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_id FROM website.friends WHERE friend_id = ?
        UNION ALL
        SELECT friend_id FROM website.friends WHERE user_id = ?) AS who
  JOIN website.users users ON users.user_id = who.user_id
  JOIN website.posts posts ON users.user_id = posts.user_id
  LEFT  JOIN website.feeds feeds ON posts.post_id = feeds.post_id
  LEFT  JOIN website.users likes ON feeds.user_id = likes.user_i)
 GROUP BY posts.pid
 ORDER BY posts.pid DESC;
```

Test output [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8934d/11).

Comment: There's still something wrong though... i think in this part `SELECT friend_id FROM website.friends WHERE friends.user_id = ?` **what if the users are friend and the other one is logged in, can the user view the post of that user?** -- as I test your code, it seems to be correct only the part on the logic of friend_id and user_id. if friend_id != user_id than all the post of the user will only about his post.

Comment: What I mean is example `A and B`. If **A** is friend with **B** then **A** now is the user_id and **B** is the friend_id. If **B** is logged in, he wont be able to view the posts of **A**.

Comment: Why not? **B** will be using another session, I see no issues. This probably depends on the logic how you specify the `user_id` for this query.

Comment: So you mean all the **?** in the query should be equal to the session id of the user?

Comment: I don't know, it is your query and your design. I supposed it is so, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: I test your code but on this part `SELECT friend_id FROM website.friends WHERE user_id = ?)` it should be equal to the friend_id if there is no friend_id found then it should be the user_id

Comment: But there's a UNION. If there's no match it doesn't matters, as first query will return `user_id` from the `users` table. Sub-query will _always_ return `user_id` and all friends, if such exists.

Comment: Have you test this one? You should test it.

Comment: on that part user_id "12042902" and "12042905" are friends now try using their user_id and record their outputs, from there your should see that the two have different outputs

Answer (score 2):

If i well understood you want to JOIN the friends table based on the friends = user_id and if not match JOIN on user_id of the friends table, so you can try with something like this :

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.screenname, posts.post_id, posts.user_id,
posts.post, posts.upload_name, posts.post_type, 
DATE_FORMAT(posts.date_posted, '%M %d, %Y %r') AS date, 
COUNT(NULLIF(feeds.user_id, ?)) AS friends, SUM(feeds.user_id = ?) AS you,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN NOT likes.user_id = ? THEN 
             CONCAT_WS(' ', likes.firstname, likes.lastname)
                    END
            ) as names
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.posts posts ON (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.feeds feeds ON (posts.post_id = feeds.post_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.users likes ON (feeds.user_id = likes.user_id)
LEFT  JOIN website.friends friends ON ((posts.user_id = friends.user_id) OR (posts.user_id = friends.friends_id) )
GROUP BY posts.pid
ORDER BY posts.pid DESC
```

I have basically added a JOIN with friends table with an OR  on the two fields that you seem want to JOIN ...

Comment: this one gives me all the posts from all the user... I'd like to clarify: `friends.friend_id` is the ID of the **friend** and the `friends.user_id` is the id of the current user. So all posts from the user's friend and the user will be outputted.